# sort country by region in combo box

Tags: c#, combobox

I've got two comboboxs, one called countryBox and the other regionBox.
countryBox is populated by the following code when the combo box is clicked:

```
var list = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(p => new RegionInfo(p.Name).EnglishName).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
countrybox.DataSource = list;
```

When a country is selected, I want the region to be automatically selected. For example if France is selected in the countryBox, Europe will be set as the region.
here's a link to the regions I'd like to have: http://tinyurl.com/y98wx8g

I'm not sure on how to go about doing this. 
If there are any better ways of populating countryBox I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be an event called OnSelectedIndexChaged for the combo box write an event handler for this that will populate the other ComboBox with what ever data you want

Comment: And one more thing..
In case the user clicks on the first element of the combo box the SelectedIndeChanged event will not trigger hence put something like `Select Region` as the first element in your regionBox